# XSLT- How to get type of xmlid and call apply template for it?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am a newbie to XSLT. I am using MagicDraw and exported the sysml model to UML xmi 2.5 version.
The xmi generated is of the format below.

```
<xmi:XMI xmlns:uml='http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/20131001'>
<uml:Model xmi:type='uml:Model' xmi:id='eee_1045467100313_135436_1' name='Model'>
<xmi:Extension extender='MagicDraw UML 18.4'>
<packagedElement xmi:type='uml:Class' xmi:id='_18_4_1_8a70262_1495692226026_145378_13658' name='a'>
<ownedAttribute xmi:type='uml:Port' xmi:id='_18_4_1_8a70262_1495692263168_183171_13795' name='p1' visibility='public' aggregation='composite'/>
</packagedElement>
<packagedElement xmi:type='uml:Class' xmi:id='_18_4_1_8a70262_1495692227629_410625_13704' name='b'>
<ownedAttribute xmi:type='uml:Port' xmi:id='_18_4_1_8a70262_1495692268225_236623_13810' name='p1' visibility='public' aggregation='composite'/>
</packagedElement>
<packagedElement xmi:type='uml:Class' xmi:id='_18_4_1_8a70262_1495692251639_26689_13750' name='IB'/>
</uml:Model>
<sysml:Block xmi:id='_18_4_1_8a70262_1495692226026_635824_13659' base_Class='_18_4_1_8a70262_1495692226026_145378_13658'/>
<sysml:Block xmi:id='_18_4_1_8a70262_1495692227629_766722_13705' base_Class='_18_4_1_8a70262_1495692227629_410625_13704'/>
    <sysml:InterfaceBlock xmi:id='_18_4_1_8a70262_1495692251640_837375_13751' base_Class='_18_4_1_8a70262_1495692251639_26689_13750'/>
```

**I have written xslt like this**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<xsl:stylesheet 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">  
  <xsl:output method="xml"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!--Handling of the Header-->
  <xsl:template match="/XMI">
    <simulinkExportBlocks>
        <xsl:for-each select="Block">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Block"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </simulinkExportBlocks>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Block">
    <compositeBlock><xsl:apply-templates select="text()|B|I|U|DEF|LINK"/></compositeBlock>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am trying to write xsl file for the conversion of uml 2.5 xmi to the custom xml.

the uml element are defined at one place and used in diagramRepresentation at other place.

I want to create the custom xml tags for every elements like Block, InterfaceBlock, Connectors, etc.,

How can I categorize it using xml id in xsl file?

Can anyone helps me in this.

Comment: Please write necessary information like the xml-block in your question (instead of as a comment) and also provide what you have tried so far and more clarification like what you mean by categorizing and what kind of output you want to have.

Comment: Thanks Gerriet :)

Comment: OK, you improved the question very much, although it is still not quite clear what the expected output would be, what categorization means and how the appearance at two places plays into this. First I would suggest learning about options to select nodes based on attributes like `<xsl:template match="Block[@xmi:id='....']"></xsl:template>`